# once the data has been fetched the state value are not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to change the state value once the data has been fetched. I can see that the JSON has been fetched on the network tab but the state value hasn't been changed. State values are logged before the fetch request, I've added await but it hasn't been resolved yet. Do I've to use useEffect for a fetch request, I've tried to use useEffect but it triggers the request once I import this hook is there a workaround?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react'

export const useSignup = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState('')

  const registerUser = async (emailAddress, password) => {
    try {
      await axios
        .post('/signup', {
          emailAddress: emailAddress,
          password: password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setStatus(res?.data.success)
          setMsg(res?.data.msg)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setStatus(err?.response.data.success)
          setMsg(err?.response.data.msg)
        })
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      setStatus(false)
      setMsg('Error Occured')
    } finally {
      console.log(msg, status)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
  return { loading, status, msg, registerUser }
}
```

Comment: How are you using your `useSignup` function? can you share a [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) ?

Comment: it is a custom hook, it's not a library. I thought I could use this hook at the signup page. Im new to coding I don't have code sandbox sorry but I just import this hook like this
"import { useSignup } from './useHooks/useSignup'
 const { loading, status, msg, registerUser } = useSignup('')"

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger your function call via a `useEffect` hook.
Also, if you are using `async/await` you shouldn't mix it with a Promise-based approach.

Modify the custom hook to accept the two parameters, add the `useEffect` call and edit your `registerUser` function:

```
export const useSignup = (emailAddress, password) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');

  const registerUser = async (emailAddress, password) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('/signup', { emailAddress, password })
      setStatus(data.success)
      setMsg(data.msg)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      setStatus(false);
      setMsg('Error Occured');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    registerUser(emailAddress, password);
  }, [])

  return { loading, status, msg, registerUser };
};
```

Then you can call your `useSignup` hook like this

```
const { loading, status, msg, registerUser } = useSignup('username', 'password')
```